# palindrome error with 8 or 9 letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I have the following code, when going through the python, the options aaabaaaa, zzzazzazz gave me the false test.Here is the code, I am not too sure on how to fix it.

```
def checkPalindrome(inputString):
    n=len(inputString)  
    #if string is one letter
    if n==1:
        return True 
    #if string has more than one letter
    for i in range (0, math.floor(n/2)) :
        if inputString[i]!=inputString[n-1-i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: Error? [tour] = False

Comment: The `else` part needs to be removed, and the `return True` is to go outside the loop.

Comment: Aren't your sample inputs supposed to give false ? *A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward as forward, such as madam or racecar.*

Comment: @AstroMax, Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant the output was True, which is wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. The main issue here is that your `else` clause has a `return True` inside the loop. What you'd want to do is *finish iterating over the string* before returning `True`. If you are familiar with boolean logic, this is the equivalent of short circuiting with `AND`.

The other issue (not really an issue, more a nitpick) is that you can just use integer division `//`, instead of having to import `math`'s `floor` function.

So,

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    for i in range(0, len(string) // 2):
        if string[i] != string[-(i + 1)]:
            return False

    return True
```

Another way of handling this would be using `all`:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    return all(x == y for x, y in zip(string, reversed(string)))
```

Or, taking advantage of python's convenient slice notation for the most concise solution possible, we have:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]
```

Comment: although this will still return `False` because the OP's inputs aren't palindromes... :)

Comment: @Julien Yes, that is my understanding, that they meant the outputs were not "as expected" (false output), haha. Mindreading OP here a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this which uses array slicing (reversing an array of chars)

```
def checkPalindrome(inputString):
    n=len(inputString)  
    #if string is one letter
    if n==1:
        return True 
    #if string has more than one letter
    return inputString==inputString[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using slicing. Strings can be accessed by index like arrays/lists and also be inverted like this.

```
def isPalindrom(string)
    return string == string[::-1]
```

the [::-1] slicing returns the reversed string, the comparision with the original string is True if it's the same otherwise false.